# Storing version in WebAssembly application

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly, wasi

I've got REST service written in C++/Qt 5.15.x. Under some URL REST service sends WASM stuff. It's a GUI application (REST client) written in C++/Qt 5.15.x. It is possible to embed some function which shows version etc? I'd like to load wasm on the server side (Debian) in "bla-bla.wasm --version" style. Or call some function from wasm via native REST service.

In fact, REST service detects wasm renewal on the server side and will notify clients about new version via WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

I am using for similar purpose `git describe` sent through Makefile as compilation definition.

In C++ there is a function which reads and parses string initialized with definition from Makefile (using as an input mentioned git output).

Makefile
`VERSION="-DVERSION_NUMBER=\"$(shell git describe)\""`

C++
`std::string version(VERSION_NUMBER);`